# Characters are getting stick together

Tags: python, python-3.x

That's just a small part of my code, when I am translating everything (In another language) the words are getting stick together.
I've tried to replace and the "sys" command but nothing works

```
def translate(phrase):
    translation = ""
    for letter in phrase:
        if letter.lower() in "h":
            if letter.isupper():
                translation = translation + "Х"
            else:
                translation = translation + "х"

        if letter.lower() in "f":
            if letter.isupper():
                translation = translation + "Ф"
            else:
                translation = translation + "ф"
        else:
            translation = translation + x
            "".join(translation)
    return translation

print(translation(input("Type: ") ) )
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you provide an example of the text you are inputting and the resulting output?

Comment: I could probably go for a dictionary lookup approach to translate letters.

Comment: [In]  print(translation(input("Type: hhh fff " ) ) )
[Out] хххффф
[Out] ххх ффф <= The correct one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer will not answer exactly how to resolve your original problem, but if I had to make "translation-table", I would do something like this:

```
a = "hHfF"
b = "xXфФ"

phrase = "Hello Friend!"
print(phrase.translate(str.maketrans(a,b))) # Outputs: Xello Фriend!
```

In the above code `a` and `b` have to be the same length. It will then go through the string `phrase` letter-by-letter and see if it's in `a` and look up the translation in `b`.

You can also call `str.maketrans` with a dictionary if that's more readable for you:

```
a = {
    "h": "x",
    "H": "X",
    "f": "ф",
    "F": "Ф"
}

phrase = "Hello Friend!"
print(phrase.translate(str.maketrans(a))) # Output: Xello Фriend!
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what's happening is that you've already set the value `x` to something else, and you never gave it a value during the function. I think that you wanted to make it `letter` instead of `x` like the following.

```
def translate(phrase):
    translation = ""
    for letter in phrase:
        if letter.lower() in "h":
            if letter.isupper():
                translation = translation + "Х"
            else:
                translation = translation + "х"

        if letter.lower() in "f":
            if letter.isupper():
                translation = translation + "Ф"
            else:
                translation = translation + "ф"
        else:
            translation = translation + letter
            "".join(translation)
    return translation
```